# How to sort out forward references for a tree data structure in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

In C++11, I want to define a tree data structure in which each node has a set of keys (`std::string`), and each key is associated with two values: another `std::string`, and a pointer to a child node in the tree.  The natural way to do this seemed to be to make a node be a `std::unordered_map`, with `std::string` keys and with values that are a `std::pair` of `std::string` and the pointer to the child node.  At present, I have this:

```
struct tree_node;

typedef std::pair<std::string, tree_node *> tree_value;

struct tree_node {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, tree_value> key_val_map;
};
```

The annoying thing is the `struct` in the middle of all this; when I'm working with these data structures I'm constantly having to make an extra step through `key_val_map`.  I'd like `tree_node` to simply be `typedef`ed as the std::unordered_map in question.  It seems like this should be possible, since `tree_value` only refers to `tree_node` by pointer; I should be able to somehow forward-declare `tree_node` so that I can define `tree_value`.  I can't find a way to do so, though.

One attempt was to typedef `tree_node` in a single line by itself:

```
typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, std::pair<std::string, tree_node *>> tree_node;
```

But that gives the error "Expected a type" when it hits the `tree_node *` in the declaration; the `typedef` has not yet happened, so the compiler doesn't know what a `tree_node` is.  Fair enough.  I also attempted to just vaguely forward-declare `tree_node`, since it seems to me that the compiler should not need to have complete information about it when I only refer to it by pointer:

```
class tree_node;

typedef std::pair<std::string, tree_node *> tree_value;

typedef std::unordered_map<std::string, tree_value> tree_node;
```

But this gives the error "Typedef redefinition with different types", on the final line.

Surely there is a way to sort out this can of worms.  If I can make it work when `tree_node` wraps the `unordered_map` inside a `struct`, why can't I make it work when I just get rid of that pointless one-member `struct`?  I basically just want to make that `struct` "transparent" – I don't want to have to keep referring to `key_val_map` in my code.  Is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you instead declare `tree_value` as a struct, `tree_node` can be a type alias.

```
struct tree_value;

using tree_node = std::unordered_map<std::string, tree_value>;

struct tree_value
{
    std::string data;
    tree_node * child; // or std::unique_ptr<tree_node> ?
};
```

As a bonus, we have more meaningful names than `first` and `second`.

Comment: This seems preferable to my previously accepted answer; there are no questions about the safety of it (which gets into technical C++ issues that are way above my pay grade), and the meaningful names are nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `tree_node` derive from the map:

```
struct tree_node : std::unordered_map<std::string, tree_value> {
    using std::unordered_map<std::string, tree_value>::unordered_map;
};
```

Comment: Oh, interesting.  I thought subclassing STL classes was unsafe in some way...?

Comment: They are unfit for polymorphism, but inheriting to avoid code repetition and expose the same interface is fine, especially if you're not adding any data member.

Comment: Opinions differ: https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2018/12/11/dont-inherit-from-std-types/

Comment: @Evg: yes, if you do some very weird stuff like shown in the article above then anything can be a problem, including inheriting from `std` types.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo So, it is better to avoid it.

Comment: @Gupta: no, it is better to not blindly follow dogmatic advice and understand pros/cons of what you're doing.

Comment: For those saying inheriting from std::unordered_map here is a bad idea: is there a better solution to my question?

Comment: @bhaller you can add a bunch of one line member functions to `tree_node` that call a member of `key_val_map`. You might not need the full api of `unordered_map`

Comment: I would remove my upvote of this answer if I could, now that I better understand the issues involved and see that there is a better solution.  SO won't let me remove my upvote, though, for some dumb reason.  It's *my* vote; why can't I change it?

Comment: @bhaller: can you enlighten me on what the issues are with this solution assuming that you don't actively try to break it like in the linked blog post?

Comment: I don't understand the linked blog post, so the issue is that there are dangers lurking that I don't understand, and that might bite me unexpectedly.  In any case, a solution that is not robust across all use cases is not really a complete solution, it seems to me.

Comment: @bhaller: so you don't understand the blog post and don't understand the dangers of inheritance, yet you want to remove your upvote. Protip: everything in C++ can be dangerous in one way or the another.